# How do I install PyYAML into local install of Python?

Tags: installation, home-directory, python

I've installed Python 2.6.4 into (a subdirectory in) my home directory
on a Linux machine with Python 2.3.4 pre-installed, because I need to
run some code that I've decided would require too much work to make it
run on 2.3.4.  (I'm not on the sudoers list for that machine.)

I was hoping I could run `~/Python-2.6.4/python setup.py install`
(from the PyYAML directory in my home directory, where I untarred the
PyYAML sources) and it would be smart enough to install it into my
local Python 2.6.4 install.  But it's not.  (See the P.S.)

Is it possible to install PyYAML into my local Python install, so that
"import yaml" will work when I invoke that Python?  If so, how do I do
that?

P.S. Here's the output when I ran `~/Python-2.6.4/python setup.py install`:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6
creating build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6/yaml
copying lib/yaml/composer.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6/yaml
copying lib/yaml/nodes.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6/yaml
copying lib/yaml/dumper.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6/yaml
copying lib/yaml/resolver.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6/yaml
copying lib/yaml/events.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6/yaml
copying lib/yaml/emitter.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6/yaml
copying lib/yaml/error.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6/yaml
copying lib/yaml/loader.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6/yaml
copying lib/yaml/cyaml.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6/yaml
copying lib/yaml/scanner.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6/yaml
copying lib/yaml/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6/yaml
copying lib/yaml/serializer.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6/yaml
copying lib/yaml/reader.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6/yaml
copying lib/yaml/representer.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6/yaml
copying lib/yaml/constructor.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6/yaml
copying lib/yaml/tokens.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6/yaml
copying lib/yaml/parser.py -> build/lib.linux-ppc64-2.6/yaml
running build_ext
creating build/temp.linux-ppc64-2.6
checking if libyaml is compilable
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall
-Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/dspitzer/Python-2.6.4/Include
-I/home/dspitzer/Python-2.6.4 -c
build/temp.linux-ppc64-2.6/check_libyaml.c -o
build/temp.linux-ppc64-2.6/check_libyaml.o
build/temp.linux-ppc64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:2:18: yaml.h: No such file
or directory
build/temp.linux-ppc64-2.6/check_libyaml.c: In function `main':
build/temp.linux-ppc64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:5: error: `yaml_parser_t'
undeclared (first use in this function)
build/temp.linux-ppc64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:5: error: (Each undeclared
identifier is reported only once
build/temp.linux-ppc64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:5: error: for each function
it appears in.)
build/temp.linux-ppc64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:5: error: syntax error
before "parser"
build/temp.linux-ppc64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:6: error: `yaml_emitter_t'
undeclared (first use in this function)
build/temp.linux-ppc64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:8: warning: implicit
declaration of function `yaml_parser_initialize'
build/temp.linux-ppc64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:8: error: `parser'
undeclared (first use in this function)
build/temp.linux-ppc64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:9: warning: implicit
declaration of function `yaml_parser_delete'
build/temp.linux-ppc64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:11: warning: implicit
declaration of function `yaml_emitter_initialize'
build/temp.linux-ppc64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:11: error: `emitter'
undeclared (first use in this function)
build/temp.linux-ppc64-2.6/check_libyaml.c:12: warning: implicit
declaration of function `yaml_emitter_delete'

libyaml is not found or a compiler error: forcing --without-libyaml
(if libyaml is installed correctly, you may need to
 specify the option --include-dirs or uncomment and
 modify the parameter include_dirs in setup.cfg)
running install_lib
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.6
error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python2.6': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't install Python correctly.  When I followed [Crast](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244393/crast)'s instructions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278028/how-do-i-work-around-this-problem-creating-a-virtualenv-environment-with-a-custom/2278059#2278059, I was then able to install PyYAML without problems.  (With no need for virtualenv.)

Answer (score 1):

Look into the `--home` or `--user` or `--prefix` switches for setup.py. These control where files get installed to.

From your build log though I'm not sure that's the problem. It looks like it's failing to find yaml.h. Is that part of the PyYAML sources? Or is it part of libyaml which PyYAML requires but you've neglected to install?

Comment: The missing yaml.h is part of the check for libyaml, which is optional.  Note below that is "libyaml is not found or a compiler error: forcing --without-libyaml".  (I don't need libyaml.)

Comment: I see, I just noticed the errors following that. So if the only problem is permissions on the install location, then the switches I listed above should help you. You could begin with `python setup.py --user install`